# Feature matching display

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, julia

I am working on matching features between two images. Now I am trying to draw the matches I have obtained and for that I was reading [this](http://learningjulia.com/2017/03/26/image-stitching-part-1.html) blogpost.
I guess the post assumes that both the images are of same size but in my situation:

`size(img1)`

> (488, 650)

`size(img2)`

> (650, 488)

I was wondering if it's possible to draw the matches without resizing the images since I guess I would have to map the coordinates of the feature points again in that case.

[This](https://github.com/SubhankarGhosh/Affine-SIFT-Julia/blob/master/randomFeatureMatching.ipynb) is what I tried to do. But I don't think it is correct since the matches are obviously all over the place.

Thanks!

Comment: rotate your image 90 degree and draw the matches. Note: your points x coordinate will become y coordinate and vice versa, so don't forget to swap your points coordinates.